# Successful POST request pending

Tags: jquery, ajax, node.js, post

I am building an app using node.js. One of my pages calls a POST request to send data to my database. The POST request is successful and the data makes it to my database, but when I check the status of the request (Chrome dev tools > network), it shows the status of the POST request as 'pending'. Does anyone know why this might be? Here is my POST request:

```
     $.ajax({
        url: "/addreport/ + data.projectId",
        type: "POST",
        data: data,
        success: function() {
          alert("Thank you for subscribing!");
        },
        error: function() {
          alert("There was an error. Try again please!");
        }
      });
```

This is important to me because I need the success callback to work to tell the user the POST request succeeded.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sending a lot of data? It sounds like there is no response from the request.

Comment: should this `"/addreport/ + data.projectId"` be `"/addreport/" + data.projectId` ?

Comment: Dave Goten makes a good point. In case that's not the issue make sure that you respond to the request in the node.js side (e.g. ``req.end()``)

Comment: What mechanism are you using to put information into your database?  It sounds like whatever is managing requests is not sending information back when it is done.

Comment: Got it - i'm not sending back a response at the moment.... thanks all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem might be that you're not sending back the response. Here is a little example code using node [route](https://www.npmjs.com/package/router) module:

```
    router.post('/', function (req, res) {
      res.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
      var jsonData = JSON.stringify(req.body);
      res.status(201);
      res.json();
    });
```

res.status(201); - sends back response as "created".

res.json(); - sends back some json data after post request was completed.

Comment: To add to @Tomas' response, you could simplify things by doing `return res.status(201).json(req.body)` as shown in here http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.json and yes it's most likely that you're not "ending" the response.

Comment: I really struggled with this, my ajax POST request inserts data through mongoose, the solution has been to define a proper callback with `res.status(201).end()`. Thanks for the helpful answer